# Synchronous HTTP call in Netty

Tags: http, netty, event-driven

My app receives an HTTP request, and in the middle of the pipeline, a call is made to another server for supporting information. The initial HTTP request can't continue through the pipeline until that response comes back. I can't use the `awaitUninterruptability()` from an I/O thread, so what's the best approach to make these calls so I don't block Netty's event loop, but put the client's pipeline on hold until my call out returns and I tell the pipeline to continue on?

Comment: After fiddling with it for awhile, I think I'm on the right track. What I'm now doing is to add another instance of the same pipeline handler to the stack immediately after the current one, passing in the response handler. Then send upstream. Then I check to see if that response handler is done (a custom method in the handler), and if not, add another instance of the handler to the pipeline, and so on. Essentially creating a loop of handlers that will "break" when the response has returned. The only problem I have now is that I overflow the stack on handlers before the response has returned...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ryan this does not sound like a good idea..

I think you should better use something like that:

```
public class HttpHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler{

    @Override
    public void messageReceived(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
        otherChannel.write(yourRequet).addListener(new ChannelFutureListener() {

            public void operationComplete(ChannelFuture future) throws Exception {

                // once the write is done we can continue in the pipeline
                ctx.sendUpstream(e);
            }
        });

        // the event stops here to get processed

    }

}
```

If you need to wait for the response then you will need to handle it in another SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler. But I think you get the idea..

Comment: So the `ctx` in that example is the context of the outbound HTTP request. So sending the event upstream only sends the event upstream for the outbound request. I need to send the event from the inbound HTTP request upstream when the `operationComplete` call is made, but not sooner. I tried sending the original event upstream (passed the inbound context into the anonymous function via a `final` context), but the originating pipeline continued to the **downstream** handlers when I didn't explicitly call `sendUpstream` from the inbound pipeline.

Comment: Ok, Norman was correct, I just didn't see it clearly. I also had a bug in my code that was executing another step in parallel when it should have been a separate pipeline handler executed later. The jist is that the client event pipeline fires the parent contexts sendUpstream when the client finishes work. Just make sure not to have anything after the client execution call that could result in parallel execution (that's unwanted).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need an [ExecutionHandler](http://netty.io/docs/stable/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/execution/ExecutionHandler.html).

Comment: Interesting... I'll try this out in the AM and see if it does what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I see in the docs `new OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(16, 1048576, 1048576)` and I'm curious if those param values are pretty common, or if they should be tuned, and if so, what are the criteria for tuning them.

Comment: These numbers are of course entirely arbitrary. Your numbers depends entirely on your specific runtime; specifically how much heap you have at your disposal-  Calculating object memory usage can be difficult. Best  approach is probably to measure heap during varying load, estimate consumption by the specific executor, and set a "conservative" limit.